# How to send delivery_sm response to a client from a smpp server

Tags: java, smpp

I have created a smpp server from logica.
It was worked fine.
But the client wanto delivery status,now how can I send thre `delivery_sm` response to client.
 please suggest.

Comment: You can Set Register delivery on. Then It will send delivery message

Comment: I already set register delivery on.. but my smpp simulator(deliver_sm) is not sending delivery response. Can you please share some code with me to send the delivery response for delivery_sm.

Comment: You need to give us a bit more information before anybody will be able to give you a full answer. What have you tried so far? What libraries are you using? What's your current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check sample logica SMPP code.
You can set delivery in the SubmitSM

```
SubmitSM request = new SubmitSM();
request.setRegisteredDelivery(true);
```

Did you run the 2 jar files that it logica comes with (smscsim.jar, smpptest.jar)
when you set setRegisteredDelivery(1) you can clearly see that simulator sends delivery pdu and testclient receive it

Comment: Actually I same only smppserver.jar..
could you pls add me on skype: asikcse

Comment: When client use deliver_sm they are not abl to get delivery pdu.